# Google Apps email keeps bouncing back

Tags: email, gmail, thunderbird, google-workspace

I use thunderbird. My email is a personal domain one set up on Google apps. It has been wonderful yet recently

when i emailed `news@members.babbel.com` the response message i got was

> Technical details of temporary
>   failure:  Google tried to deliver your
>   message, but it was rejected by the
>   recipient domain. We recommend
>   contacting the other email provider
>   for further information about the
>   cause of this error. The error that
>   the other server returned was: 450 450
>   4.1.8 : Sender address rejected: Domain not found (state 14).

when i emailed `upload@box.net` the response message was

> Technical details of temporary
>   failure:  Google tried to deliver your
>   message, but it was rejected by the
>   recipient domain. We recommend
>   contacting the other email provider
>   for further information about the
>   cause of this error. The error that
>   the other server returned was: 451 451
>   SPF lookup failure (#4.3.0) (state
>   13).

And then my email still works to other destinations like name@yahoo.com and name@gmail.com.

I'm completely lost to where the problem is from any kind of help would be sincerely appreciated.

**UPDATE:** Please read the comments on Ayaz's answer.

**Resolved:** Name servers on my domain had been deleted somehow. It was not hosting yet my dns settings which were missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subdomain for the first email address that you tried to send email to, `members.babbel.com`, fails to resolve. This explains why Gmail reported a `Domain not found` error when you tried to send an email to that address.

The second error leads me to believe that the mail server that handles the `upload@box.net` mailbox requires a strict SPF record check, which tries to determine whether the incoming email is authentic and not SPAM. You can read about SPF over [here](http://old.openspf.org/index.html). I am wondering that there are possibly some settings in Thunderbird that you can play with in order to provide the correct information for an SPF check to pass successfully. Perhaps Google lists these settings somewhere on their help pages.

Comment: Thanks Ayaz, I thinks its my domain that fails to resolve actually. As you see the message returned was not by google but the other mail server. They check the authenticity of your email by checking your domain status header.

I used host-tracker to find out that my domain fails to resolve in most locations. "Failure("Domain lookup failure:example.com Exception:Not_found")". I'm not sure if this is either my domain name (from godaddy) or if my hosting is at fault. I've contacted my hosting to follow up on it further.

Comment: Following on from Ayaz's comment - Have you created _your_ SPF record for your Apps domain?

more info here: http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=33786

I have 5 domains set up with google apps for mail and had to add this record to all of them

Comment: @Mohammad: Right, okay. I may have mis-read the error bit. But, for me at least, the domain `members.babbelcom` is not resolving either, which led to come to that conclusion.

Comment: @Sheve, Thank you i had no idea such a setting existed, I would need to implement that on all my domains as well. Thanks so much!
@Ayaz, Yes that is true. members.babbel.com does not resolve currently . Which could also have caused the error.

Answer (score 0):

I spent all day searching for a solution and then found it was caused because the Mail Exchanger in setting in cPanel was set to local when clearly it should have been set to Remote.

See: https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/local-mail-exchanger-or-remote.213151/

**Notes**
Local Mail Exchanger: The server should always deliver mail to itself and always accept mail from external sources. Mail sent through this server will never be delivered to an external location.
Remote Mail Exchanger: Configure the server to deliver all mail to external locations and refuse any deliveries from an external source. Mail sent through this server will never be delivered to a local mail inbox.